# Nested Transactions Not Supported

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to delete a record in a MySQL database using Entity Framework 6 in C# and received a 'Nested Transactions Are not Supported' error. I did not tell me anything else about why this error is happening.
Today I was trying to find out why my MySQL entity was throwing an exception described as 'Nested Transactions Not Supported' and all of my searches returned closed topics with no answers.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had a table with a foreign keys without a cascade on delete and i did not manually remove the child records. For Example: 
Table A - the table i was deleting a record from.
Table B - has foreign key to record I am deleting in Table A (which does have a cascade on delete setup.)
Table C - has a foreign key to record in Table B that would be deleted by the Cascaded Delete, but it does not have a cascaded delete on its foreign key relationship to table B.

So If you get this error, look for child records that need to be deleted, or a cascade on delete that is missing.